# Quickly sketching the power function $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$

Tags: functions, normed-spaces

What is the best way to quickly sketch $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ by hand, without using a graphing device?

One can quickly imagine that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a circle. But how does one quickly imagine what $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ should look like?

Comment: To be honest, the best way I can think of is to know beforehand... when you were young you didn't know what the equation for a circle looked like when graphed, but you were taught so.

Comment: The shape in question is a special type of [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), called [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to become familiar with what the unit sphere looks like in different [$p$-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm). The curve given by $x^{p}+y^{p}=1^{p}$ is the unit sphere in the normed space $(\mathbb{R}^{2},\lVert\cdot\lVert_{p})$. When $p=2$ this is just a circle. As $p$ increases the sphere bloats outward until it reaches a square with side length $2$ centered at the origin. This corresponds to the case $p=\infty$. See this picture from Wikipedia:

[image: "Vector norms". Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via Commons - https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_norms.svg#/media/File:Vector_norms.svg]

For $p\in(0,1)$ the '$p$-norm' is not actually a norm, but we can still draw the shape traced out by $x^{p}+y^{p}=1^{p}$. You can try it; it looks like a diamond but with the sides sucked inwards, towards the origin. You might want to take a look at [the Wikipedia page on the unit sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere).

Comment: A beautiful observation... thanks for sharing!

Comment: Marvellous. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome.